# Remove Line from Canvas in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Hy guys, I'm trying to delete a Line previously created by button pressed. I also want the line to be deleted by button pressed. There are a large number of lines on my canvas, so I've tried selecting it by name to delete it but I failed. Also I tried by Uid and did not work.

Here is the code for the line created:

```
 private void butonAdaugare_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        Linie1.Y2 = Linie1.Y2 + 21;
        Linie2.Y2 = Linie2.Y2 + 21;
        Linie3.Y2 = Linie3.Y2 + 21;
        Linie4.Y2 = Linie4.Y2 + 21;

        Line linienoua = new Line();
        linienoua.Uid = "LinieNoua" + i;
        linienoua.X1 = 10;
        linienoua.Y1 = Linie4.Y2;
        linienoua.X2 = 670;
        linienoua.Y2 = Linie4.Y2;
        linienoua.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
        linienoua.Stroke = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Black;
        linienoua.StrokeThickness = 1;
        canvas1.Children.Add(linienoua);

        i++;

        foreach (Line l in canvas1.Children.OfType<Line>())
        {
            for (int j = 2; j < 15; j++)
            {
                if (l.Name == "V" + j)
                    l.Y2 = l.Y2 + 21;
            }
        } 
    }
```

And this is the removal part by Uid:

```
    private void butonStergere_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (Linie1.Y2 > 101 && Linie2.Y2 > 101 && Linie3.Y2 > 101 && Linie4.Y2 > 101)
        {
            Linie1.Y2 = Linie1.Y2 - 21;
            Linie2.Y2 = Linie2.Y2 - 21;
            Linie3.Y2 = Linie3.Y2 - 21;
            Linie4.Y2 = Linie4.Y2 - 21;
        }


        foreach (Line l in canvas1.Children.OfType<Line>())
        {
            if (l.Uid == "LinieNoua" + i)
                canvas1.Children.Remove(l);

            for (int j = 2; j < 15; j++)
            {
                if (l.Name == "V" + j && l.Y2 > 91)
                    l.Y2 = l.Y2 - 21;
            }
        }

        i--;           
    }
```

Any thoughts on this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without [a good, *minimal*, *complete* code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it is hard to provide an answer with a high level of confidence. You have left too much information out of your question to know for sure what the problem is.

However, from the code you did post, there does seem to be one obvious problem: the value of `i` is being decremented only after the code to remove the line, but it seems that variable contains the index value for the *next* line to be added, not the most recently-added one.

It seems likely to me that if you simply move the decrement to occur prior to the loop that finds and removes the object, it would work:

```
private void butonStergere_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    if (Linie1.Y2 > 101 && Linie2.Y2 > 101 && Linie3.Y2 > 101 && Linie4.Y2 > 101)
    {
        Linie1.Y2 = Linie1.Y2 - 21;
        Linie2.Y2 = Linie2.Y2 - 21;
        Linie3.Y2 = Linie3.Y2 - 21;
        Linie4.Y2 = Linie4.Y2 - 21;
    }

    i--;           
    Line lineToRemove = null;

    foreach (Line l in canvas1.Children.OfType<Line>())
    {
        if (l.Uid == "LinieNoua" + i)
        {
            lineToRemove = l;
        }

        for (int j = 2; j < 15; j++)
        {
            if (l.Name == "V" + j && l.Y2 > 91)
                l.Y2 = l.Y2 - 21;
        }
    }

    if (lineToRemove != null)
    {
        canvas1.Children.Remove(lineToRemove);
    }
}
```

**<edit>**
From your description in the comments, it sounds like when you made my originally suggested change, the code simply crashed (i.e. "the program exits directly", as you put it). Since you didn't provide a complete code example, there is no way for me to actually test any proposed solution, but I strongly suspect the crash you are seeing is due to the fact that the code attempts to modify (remove an element from) the `canvas1.Children` collection, which is the same collection that is being enumerated.

I have edited the proposed code change to avoid performing that illegal operation. Instead, the element to remove is simply noted in a local variable, and it is removed at the end, after the enumeration of all of the children has completed.
**</edit>**

For future reference, this seems like an excellent scenario for a debugger. If you were to simply set a breakpoint in the `butonStergere_Click()` method and step through each iteration of the loop, looking for the object you expect to be removed, it would be readily apparent when you find that object why the code itself wasn't identifying it.

Most bugs happen because we as a programmer have made an assumption about something that turns out to not be true. The best way to find bugs then is to use a debugger and examine the validity of each and every assumption we made, until we find the discrepancy.

Comment: Thank you for the answer Peter, it seems that putting i--; before looping through the lines the program exits directly. Yes that was my original problem, the previously added line is not identified. The code that I posted contains all the items in my program itself, no line of code from those 2 methods was missed. I am trying to find the last added line by it's name or by it's Uid, that is why I do not decrement i ( where i is a global variable in the main window ) to try to catch it's last value.

Comment: What I'm trying to build is a program that will build a table dynamically line by line as more rows are added ( for geotechnical engineering purposes, I myself am a geotechnical engineer and I want a program to help me with earth's parameters ). The add method works just fine, it's only the last added horizontal line that will not delete, everything else works without a hickup.

Comment: _"the program exits directly"_ -- I don't know what that means. _"The code that I posted contains all the items in my program itself, no line of code from those 2 methods was missed"_ -- please read the link I provided to understand what is meant by **minimal** and **complete**. The two methods you posted do not constitute a **complete** code example, and even among those two methods, there is code that clearly is not needed for the purpose of illustrating this question, and so is also not **minimal**.

Comment: Actually, looking at this again, I think I do know what you mean by _"the program exits directly"_. Indeed, it proves that my suggestion _does_ fix the bug you are asking about. But you have yet another bug: you are trying to modify the same collection that you are enumerating. This isn't allowed. I'll edit the code example to provide a suggested alternative.

Comment: That was brilliant Peter thank you ! 

Yes indeed the error provided at exit stated "An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in PresentationCore.dll

Additional information: The enumerator is not valid because the collection changed "

I thought that the reason for the error was that I was trying to remove another element type ( other than the Line in the enumeration ) but your answer proved that it does not allow me to modify in the enumeration. Your fix did the trick exactly how you said it and where you put it in the code. Thank you !